# Where can I find a compilation of League Judgements?

Tags: league-of-legends

I'm looking for an easy to browse list of League Judgements of the various champions. I've found copies of them on the individual champions on the wikia, but no luck finding a list of just the judgements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lore subforum on Riot's official forums has exactly what you're asking for in one of the [stickied threads.](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=256575)

Normally, I'd bring the list here as well, but due to differing syntax between the Riot Forums and Stack Exchange, I don't think it's worth the bother.